# Another issue about LINQ

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, sorting

It's possibly to add a field in this LINQ instruction to exclude files containing a word when sorting the list?

```
Dim Files As List(Of IO.FileInfo) = _
Get_Files(Directory, True, ValidExtensions) _
.OrderBy(Function(x) x.Name.ToLower.Contains("word")) _
.ThenBy(Function(x) x.Extension).ToList
```

What I want is to add a field to exclude from the creation of the list files which contains a word, I know I can exclude them in the function who get the files (Get_Files) but I want to know if it's possibly to do it using LINQ.

Comment: You know that you need to use `OrderByDescending` if you want files which name contains `"word"` at the top?

Comment: I didn't knew that but anyways I want them at the bottom, thanks for comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim Files As List(Of IO.FileInfo) = _
Get_Files(Directory, True, ValidExtensions) _
.Where(Function(x) Not x.Name.ToLower.Contains("your word")) _
.OrderBy(Function(x) x.Name.ToLower.Contains("word")) _
.ThenBy(Function(x) x.Extension).ToList
```

Answer (score 4):

Add a `Where` clause

```
.Where(Function(x) x.Name.ToLower.Contains("skip") = False)
.OrderBy(Function(x) x.Name.ToLower.Contains("word")) _
.ThenBy(Function(x) x.Extension).ToList
```